# How to call mobile service in an android app via background service or queue them if offline

Tags: android, azure, service, cloud, azure-mobile-services

**Detail**:
I have developed an android native application on ADT.

App performs ADD , Search and update operations on SQL database hosted on Windows Azure cloud platform.

All the operations are performed by calling a Mobile Service built on Windows Azure Cloud platform.

**Problem Description**:
Every time I want to ADD a new record via UI of app, my app calls mobile service and get hang till the operation completes.
I want to do this operation but do not want user to wait for it to complete.
Additionally when there is no network, user addition should be kept in queue for later addition.

**Ideal Scenario**: I want to display Addition operation in pending status to user and make that as a background process till the time it completes.

**Note**: There can be many ADD operation going on by multiple users. Need to keep that in mind.

Please suggest options to do this.
Free to ask questions in case of any query regarding problem statement.

Thanks
Anshul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use AsyncTask to do work in the background and update the UI for the User or Pop a notification in OnPostExecute which means background work has been done.

For Queuing when No Network:

You would have to user a Service with BroadCastReceiver which listener for Network-Connectivity. Once the BroadCast Receiver Receives that Internet is Connected, You can then start calling the mobile service.

But Let me add that the Queued Data has to be Saved so you would have to create a SQlLite database or save the Data to a file on the Phone, which you can retrieve the data from, when the BroadCastReceiver is notified that connection is back